# OAuth authentication in apache airflow (Google Cloud Composer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have successfully written an API in Python to read Gmail message, URL from the message, call the URL  and store CSV file, however, when I am deploying this in Apache Airflow [Google Cloud Composer] I am getting the below error (shown in the screenshot). I believe it because my code cannot find the token.json and credential.json. I tried many ways, almost did 2 days of research to fix this problem, but couldn't find any solution.

Please note: The dag file and API file are coming from the cloud storage bucket. Even the token.json and credential.json are in the same bucket.

[image]

Error in the apache airflow

[image]
I am using OAuth 2.0 key for the Gmail API:

[image]

```
import os.path
import logging
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import sys
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
# import the required libraries 
from googleapiclient.discovery import build 
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow 
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request 
import pickle 
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from apiclient.discovery import build

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
    

full_date = datetime.datetime.now()
day = full_date.strftime("%d")
month = full_date.strftime("%b")
Year = full_date.strftime("%Y")

day_month_year = day+" "+month+" "+Year
subject = ""

    
def get_data_from():
    try:
        
        """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
        Lists the user's Gmail labels.
        """
        creds = None
        # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        # time.
        
        if os.path.exists('token.json'):
            creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        #show_chatty_threads(service)
        # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    'credentials.json', SCOPES)
                creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
            # Save the credentials for the next run
            with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
                token.write(creds.to_json())

        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        
        # Call the Gmail API
        threads = service.users().threads().list(userId='me').execute().get('threads', [])
        for thread in threads:
            tdata = service.users().threads().get(userId='me', id=thread['id']).execute()
            nmsgs = len(tdata['messages'])
            msg = tdata['messages'][0]['payload']
            #print(msg['headers'])
            subject = ''
            for header in msg['headers']:
                if header['name'] == 'Subject':
                    subject = header['value']
                    
            for header in msg['headers']:
                if header['name'] == 'Date':
                    #print(len(header['value']))
                    date_email = header['value']
                    #if date_email == 'xyz':
                    if day_month_year in date_email:
                        print(date_email)
                        txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=thread['id']).execute()
                        #print(txt)
                        # Get value of 'payload' from dictionary 'txt' 
                        payload = txt['payload'] 
                        # The Body of the message is in Encrypted format. So, we have to decode it. 
                        # Get the data and decode it with base 64 decoder. 
                        parts = payload.get('parts')[0] 
                        data = parts['body']['data'] 
                        #print(data)
                        data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
                        #print(data)
                        decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data.encode('utf-8')).decode("utf-8")
                        #print(decoded_data)
                        #print(type(decoded_data))

                        #find URL in email body 
                        URL = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", decoded_data).group("url")
                        URL = URL.replace(">","")
                        print(URL)
                        req = requests.get(URL)
                        url_content = req.content
                        print(url_content)
                        # Load into a dataframe
                        df = pd.read_excel(url_content)
                        print(df)
                        # Write to csv
                        file_name = subject+"-"+day_month_year+".csv" 
                        print(file_name)
                        bucket.blob('dags/orchestra/xyz/abc_temp/'+f'{file_name}').upload_from_string(df, 'text/csv')
                        df.to_csv(file_name)
                            
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a a full path that is not relative as explained in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket)? Example: '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/orchestra/credentials.json'. Ideas from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175674) might also help although it is about Bigquery.

Answer (score 0):

try add this to 'service' API  call `cache_discovery=False` for the `file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0`

example:

```
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
```

Comment: You should also add some explanation of the answer, see how do I write a good answer [answer].